# Regex to match surrounding text

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I need to replace "something[*anything*]" with "somethingElse(*anything*)", the tricky part is *anything* could be anything, and I don't want to replace that. Is it possible to do with regex?

P.S. In real scenario I'd be using PHPStorm to look / replace it. It would help me a lot to show me what to put exactly at the find window.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idea: Capture 'anything' in a capturing group in regex. Then, back reference it in the replacement.

For example: search for `something[([^]]*)\]` and replace with `somethingElse($1)`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with this: Text to find: something\[(.*)\] Text to replace something\($1\) would appreciate if you could update your answer.

Comment: Strange, `something[(.*)]` doesn't looks like regex for me. Anyway, will update the answer.

Comment: The problem with this method though, when there is this text: something["one"] something["two"] it will be replaced with something("one"] something["two") is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: If we assume there will be no `]` in the "one" and "two", we could search for this instead: `something\[([^]]*)\]`. For this to really work, please ensure the search is done in regex.